# Banshee stopped working properly

Tags: banshee

So... I was having some trouble with Banshee and I decided to uninstall it. I tried to install it again but now when I click to open, Banshee doesn't open. I thought that the problem could be broken packages, or missing plugins, but it seems the problem isn't this. 
Does anybody know what to do? = /

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding the Banshee's stable PPA:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
```

Or from the unstable PPA:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/banshee-daily
```

Update the repositories:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

**NOTE**: Please add only one PPA.

Next, please remove all banshee packages and configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get remove banshee* --purge
```

Install banshee:

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install banshee && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Good, please in "feedback" in this answer, in a question "Was this post useful to you?" select "Yes".